# How to call a specific overridden method in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding

I have a 'Modify' method overridden multiple times in inheriting classes that takes an int and has a switch to decide what to do with it.

If the int is not known by the method it is passed to the inherited class' version of it.

Now, under certain circumstances different overrides might have different cases for the same int (see case 10).

```
public abstract class A
{
  public virtual void Modify(int i)
  {
    switch(i)
    {
      //switch cases
    }
  }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
  public override void Modify(int i)
  {
    switch (i)
    {
      //switch cases
      case 10:
        //Under certain circumstances, this case should be used
        break;
      default:
        base.Modify(i);
        break;
    }
  }
}

public class C : B
{
  public override void Modify(int i)
  {
    switch (i)
    {
      //switch cases
      case 10:
        //By default, this case should be used
        break;
      default:
        base.Modify(i);
        break;
    }
  }
```

My question: Given an instance of class C, how do I access a specific method overridden by C without referring to it through 'base'?

Comment: You can't specify which parent method to call. you can only put conditions inside ur methods to achieve this. However i m not sure why would u need this.

Comment: can't you do? : ``C objC = new C();
 objC.Modify(10);``

Comment: What do you mean by *"How do I access a specific method overriden by C"*? An instance of which type do you hold? Of the base?

Comment: I hold an instance of C that is of type A.

`A myObject = new C();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object is an instance of Class C, no matter you are keeping it in A or C, it would call the `Modify` function of C Class:

```
C objectC1 = new C();
A objectC2 = new C();
```

objectC1 does the same as objectC2. They both call the `C.Modify(int)`

Comment: Oh, well. Thanks for the answer. It seems I will have to approach this differently.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. You would need to do a non-virtual method call, but C# simply doesn't do this for classes.

If you try to cast the object you will end up with a recursive method call.

However there is a solution, though it is a little unpleasant. What you want is to call a non-virtual method as though it's virtual, and this can be achieved by dynamic dispatch.

```
public class A
{
    public int Modify()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new int Modify()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public new int Modify()
    {
        return ((A)this).Modify();
    }
}


public void Main()
{
    dynamic obj = new C();
    Conosle.WriteLine(c.Modify());
}
```

This should return 1. But I would like to think that there is probably a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that. If you really need to do that, then your application has a wrong design.